# Extremely slow Viewstate

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I have a test code that works perfectly fine on a local testing server and it takes 40 s to react on the release server.

Here is the code, and is it simple pager, but the ViewState is a List containg aprox 50,000 items.

This is only one time page that I use to set photo type, but what I dont understand is that an average photo load on on local (slower) server is under 1s and on production server is 40s???

I did all kind of modification to the code, but I dont really think it is the code (no matter how stupid the idea of putting 50,000 items in ViewState is). What could be other serve limitations that would slow down code execution

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Photo.aspx.cs" Inherits="Admin.Web.Test.WebForm1" EnableViewState="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="sc">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="up" UpdateMode=Conditional ViewStateMode=Enabled>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkPrevious" Width=100 Height=600 OnClick="lnkPrevious_Click" Font-Size=48 Text="<"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <asp:Panel runat="server" Width="800" Height="500" ScrollBars="Both">
                            <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgPic" />
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkNext" Width=100 Height=600 OnClick="lnkNext_Click" Font-Size=48 Text=">"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <asp:DataList runat="server" ID="dli" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                            OnLoad="dli_Load">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <table style="width: 75px; height: 75px; border: 1px solid #cccccc; margin-right: 2px;
                                    margin-bottom: 2px;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center">
                                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkSelect" OnCommand="lnkSelect_Click" Width="75"
                                                Height="75" Text='<%# Eval("pictype") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("PicTypeID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkReportProblem" Style="border: 1px solid #cccccc;
                                    margin-right: 2px; margin-bottom: 2px;" Width="200" Height="100" Text="Prijavi problem za ovu sliku"></asp:LinkButton>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:DataList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="labPicID" Font-Size="16"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the network connection like between you and the local server, and you and the production server?

Comment: @AdrianWragg i am working on the local (testing) server and sql and asp.net application are on the same network (production server). Items are loaded fast on both servers, but viewstate is horrible on production server. cant find a reason why..

Comment: @AdrianWragg and if i use Session instead of Viewstate it is extremely fast on both servers. Session could be solution but I would really want to know for future reference what is wrong with a use of Viewstate on production server.

Comment: Is the viewstate the same size on both for the same options?

Comment: @AdrianWragg they are using the same result set return from sql